# NiMH 1.2V 1/3 AA 280 mAh is it possible the claim made for size and capacity?

Tags: batteries, nimh, battery-chemistry

I am browsing some batteries to use for a wearable project.Initially I wanted to go with Lipos but upon stumbling upon this [link](http://www.smallbattery.company.org.uk/sbc_industrial_nimh.htm) I am amazed at NiMH and the variety of size, shape and battery capacity. I am not sure if it too good to be true for the capacities claimed here. **Does anyone with experience of using NiMh thinks that these claims might be true?** Especially given the form factor I am very interested in

**NiMH 1/V150H 150 mAh with pins** as I can connect a few of these in series to get a higher voltage and get rid of Boost circuit in my project. The form factor also gives me the flexibility to make optimal use of the space to make the circuitry a part of clothing itself. My project sinks 100mA average with pulses at 600mA at 5V. The max time I need for the project to run is 2 hours runtime max as it in Idle the consumption is just 10mA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2200mAh AA (14500) NiMH cells are available commonly, so 280mAh for a 1/3AA actually sounds a little low. I would expect 600mAh from that size instead.

Rather than putting multiple 1/V150Hs in series you might be better with one or more 4/V150Hs or 5/V150Hs on the same page. Putting them in parallel will let you easily hit your 2h life.